# где найти csrf token

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

для запроса через requests нужно передать csrf token подскажите как его найти и как передать

Comment: открой страницу того сайта, на которую хочешь войти(где есть форма л логина) и проанализируй html код там должен быть этот токен

Comment: А как его передать

Comment: по сути это просто поле `input type="hidden"`, так что передать его можно так же как и другие поля формы